# Android action bar settings option not show on real device

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i have action bar which have back button and settings option . when i run app on emmulator it show both back button and settings option. 
like as
[image]

but on real device it not show settings option 
like as
[image]

please tell me how to fix it?

this is my code of activity

```
 public class AddNewDish extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new_dish);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.option, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }
```

this is menu xml code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: in your device try to press option button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put below code on **onCreate()** of **ActionBarActivity**:

```
try {
  ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
  Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");

  if (menuKeyField != null) {
    menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
    menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
  }
}
catch (Exception e) {

}
```

**Done**